# FINDSTR to find spaces

Tags: regex, batch-file, findstr

I am unable to find space which is appearing after opening and before closing of the tags/elements. I am using below line to obtain HTML elements

```
findstr /N /O /R /C /S "<p[^>]*>" *.html >> tag.log    
findstr /N /O /R /C /S "</p[^>]*>" *.html >> tag.log
```

I want to find elements which are contains space immediately after opening and closing of the elements/tags

Please help me

I am using Windows 7

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
findstr /N /O /R /S /c:"<p[^>]*> " /c:"</p[^>]*> " *.html > tag.log
```

You need to property indicate the search strings with `/c:"...."` switches and include the spaces in the quoted expression